# AngularJS 1.5 component styles aren't applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Several times I noticed that styles added for AngularJS 1.5 components aren't really applied and now I encountered this again and can't google the reason why it happens so. The situation: I've got view `home` and component `bt-table` inside it.

Simplified template:

```
<section id="home">
    <bt-table data="hc.tableData" options="hc.tableOptions"></bt-table>
</section>
```

In styles (sass) for `home` I write the following selector:

```
#home
    bt-table
            margin: 0 0 30px 0
```

Then I see it's not applied, go to devtools and see that styles are actually parsed by browser:

[image]

Also intresting: when I hover component in elements, I see this:

[image]

Notice how element isn't highlighted with blue as normal even though it has non-zero size?

So, why can it work so? Has it something to do with AngularJS template compilation process (it's my guess) or there are another reasons?

**UPD:** if I set `border: 10px solid red` for element, that gets rendered:
[image]

**UPD:** the markup inside bt-table looks like this:

```
<section id="table">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Table</div>
        <table st-table="tc.data.data" class="table table-striped">

            <!-- HEADERS, SORTING AND SEARCHBARS -->
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="header in tc.data.headers" st-sort="{{header.sortsearch}}" ng-bind="header.title"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if="tc.options.search === 'every'">
                <th ng-repeat="header in tc.data.headers">
                    <input st-search="{{header.sortsearch}}" placeholder="search for {{header.title.toLowerCase()}}" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if="tc.options.search === 'all'">
                <th>
                    <input st-search placeholder="search in all columns" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <!-- CONTENT -->
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in tc.data.data">
                <td ng-repeat="column in row" ng-bind="column"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

            <!-- PAGINATION -->
            <tfoot ng-if="tc.options.pagination">
            <tr ng-if="tc.tdata.options.pagination.type === 'buttons'">
                <td colspan="5" class="text-right">
                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="tc.tdata.options.pagination.itemsByPage" class="no-margin"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if="tc.options.pagination.type === 'input'">
                <td colspan="5" class="text-right">
                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="tc.options.pagination.itemsByPage" st-template="components/l-table/custom-pagination.custom.html" class="no-margin"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not going to be able to help you with just a picture.  Need some type of code that shows your problem.  Show us the markup behind the photo.

Comment: @Nix sorry, forgot to tab it, so it was escaped, edited now

Comment: Have you tried just putting a simple "colored" border around it.  Because there is nothing that should be preventing your style from being applied.

Comment: @Nix tried it, updated original post

Comment: @Nix thanks, by the way, it shows, that styles are indeed applied, just the strange way

Comment: @Nix looks like issue is with size of component, it's not matching size shown by devtools

Comment: What type of markup is in `btn-table` ?

Comment: @Nix sorry for late response, I added component template to original post, it's rather big chunk of code, but I decided not to crop it to show basic structure of inner template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are targeting a custom element and chrome is setting it to `display:inline`.  Two options:

---

**Option 1**:  Add a style of "block".

```
bt-table{
   display: block;
}
```

---

**Option 2** use replace(which is what I would do).  You would set  `replace:true` on the directive and then targeting the first child of section which isn't a custom element and will display to `block`:

```
<section id="table">
```

Other suggestions pick something else besides id=table .  `id`s are supposed to be unique on the page.  I'd recommend adding a class selector to target:

e.g.

```
<section class="btn-table">
```

Then update your styles to:

```
#home .bt-table{
    margin: 0 0 30px 0
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it was chrome default display: inline style